Package `keystroke` not drawing borders all the way

As the image shows, the left edge, right edge, part of the top, and part of the bottom all display just fine. However, part of the key is supposed to extend to cover everything in the key. Why is this not happening now? For reference, this is in RStudio, as an attempt to knit my RMarkdown file to a PDF. I know that, normally, the key buttons would stretch all the way. However, whether the issue is with RMarkdown or some conflicting package, this is not working as it should. What gives? Thanks
Also, let me provide a short RMarkdown file to reproduce this.
---
title: "Test Document"
author: "Author Name"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{keystroke}
output:
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

# Test Document

\Alt\Break\Ctrl\Shift\keystroke{Command}


The problem is, once again, that for some inexplicable reasons rmarkdown and/or pandoc think that adding
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}

to every preamble is a good idea.
This breaks the keystroke package, which normally puzzles the border together from 3 different images: one for the left edge and corners, one for the right edge and corners and one to connect them at the top and bottom. The connecting bit needs to be streched to adjust to the width of your button, but rmarkdown/pandoc disable this by forcing the keepaspectratio option upon your document.
You can undo the worst of it like this:
---
title: "Test Document"
author: "Author Name"
header-includes:
   - \setkeys{Gin}{keepaspectratio=false}
   - \usepackage{keystroke}
output:
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

# Test Document

\Alt\Break\Ctrl\Shift\keystroke{Command}



That fixed it! Thank you! If you happen to know why this works, I would like to know so that I can understand this better.

@PrivateEye The keystroke package needs to be able to stretch the borders to the required width. If rmarkdown/pandoc forces the keepaspectratio option upon your document, the keystrokes package can no longer do this.

@PrivateEye If you have time, please ask rmarkdown and/or pandoc to stop doing this.

As an alternative, the menukeys package could be used instead of keystroke.
